# How to make some edges thicker and in a different color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have the following TikZ code. I would like to make some of the edges thicker and to change their color to red but only in the second overlay.  How can you do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, tikzmark, chains, fit,
    shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, text width=8.5cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen}
]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (0,3) {};
    \node (C) at (3,0) {};
    \node (D) at (3,3) {};
    \node (E) at (4.5, 1.5) {};
    \node (F) at (-3, 3) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \path [-] (A) edge  (B);
    \path [-] (A) edge  (C);
    \path [-] (B) edge  (D);
    \path [-] (D) edge  (C);
    \path [-] (D) edge  (E);
    \path [-] (C) edge  (E);
    \path [-] (F) edge  (B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `alt` style from `overlay-beamer-styles`. It allows you to switch styles on specific overlays. In this example I use

```
subvert/.style={alt=<#1>{every edge/.style={draw=blue,ultra thick}}{}}
```

to change the edge style on a given overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, tikzmark, chains, fit,
    shapes,overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, text width=8.5cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen}
%  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt,text width=2cm},
%  ->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (0,3) {};
    \node (C) at (3,0) {};
    \node (D) at (3,3) {};
    \node (E) at (4.5, 1.5) {};
    \node (F) at (-3, 3) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick},
              subvert/.style={alt=<#1>{every edge/.style={draw=blue,ultra thick}}{}}]
    \path [-] (A) edge  (B);
    \path [-,subvert=2] (A) edge  (C);
    \path [-] (B) edge  (D);
    \path [-,subvert=2] (D) edge  (C);
    \path [-,subvert=2] (D) edge  (E);
    \path [-] (C) edge  (E);
    \path [-] (F) edge  (B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to make the edge even thicker?

Comment: Just replace `ultra thick` by `line width=3pt`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.